# I am just starting with Linkedin API and I was wondering if their was a way to search for a companies number of employees based on a certain date?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have read all the documentation I could and have yet to find an answer.
I know that the API is not the most intuitive and I know how to search for companies based on a keyword but I cannot figure out if you can get a company's number of employees at a certain date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make an oauth authentication to get access to linkedin in windows or chrome extension?What is the approach you are following?